# I'm trying to draw a centered square in graphics Java, but it's not centered on the window

Tags: graphics, drawing

I'm new to graphics, but I'm trying to draw a 100x100 sized square with red and green sides that is centered in the middle of a 400x200 sized window.  For some reason, every time I run it, it's not centered, but the math looks correct to me.  I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Exercise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Graphical Greeting");
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.setSize(400,200);
        JPanel pane = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
        
        pane.add(new Greeting());
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Greeting extends JComponent {
    public Greeting() {
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        
//      red and green square
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawLine(150, 50, 250, 50);
        g.drawLine(150, 150, 250, 150);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawLine(150, 50, 150, 150);
        g.drawLine(250, 50, 250, 150);

    }
}
```